# How to bound variable which I pass through function to a specific parameter

Tags: javascript

Very stupid question. For example I have a variable data and I have function DoSomething with two parameters par1 and par2. they are both optional parameters that would be null if I pass nothing. But I have only one variable data which I want to bound to the second parameter without touching first parameter. In different language I should write something like `DoSomething(par2 = data)` or `DoSomething(par2: data)` but all these examples will raise exception `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )`. So what I did wrong?

Comment: So you want to call the function without the first parameter but with the second one set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two optional parameters in JavaScript, just pass `undefined` to the first argument.

```js
DoSomething(undefined, data);
```

`undefined` is the default value of arguments when they aren't passed in (`DoSomething()` would have both arguments be `undefined`) except when you set default values for optional arguments.

Another alternative is to pass in the arguments as an object, which requires changing the definition of the function and all calls to it: (`??` is the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
function DoSomething(args) {
  const par1 = args.par1 ?? "default value";
  const par2 = args.par2 ?? "default value";
}

// ....
DoSomething({ par2: "custom value" });
DoSomething({ par1: "custom value", par2: "customValue" });
```

Using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [JSDocs](https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/) allows you to give guidance on how to send arguments in the IDE

Comment: It is just example. Imagine that instead of two parameters function can have 5 or more. If I will pass undefiend to all these parameters except last it will be not very good. Your alternative way is much better but assign values to par1, par2... par10 every time like that will break the principle DRY, doesn't it? But if these ways are only ones so ok I will use the second way.

Comment: Another way you can try to dry  is to make another function with a slightly different name that accepts less arguments but calls the full argument version. This is the concept of "overloading" in other languages, but that involves multiple functions with the same name but different arguments which itself can't be done in JavaScript/Python since strict typing is not enforced.

Answer (score 1):

You always can pass **undefined** or **null** as first parameter. SO it will be something like this:

```
DoSomething(undefined, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple optional parameters, if you don't want to pass undefined.. you should use an object as the parameter.

```js
// instead of DoSomething(param1, param2)
function DoSomething(param = {}) {
  const { param1, param2 } = param;

  //..do something with param1 and param2
}

DoSomething({ param2: 'somevalue' })
```

If you consider using typescript, it's even better because you can add the
type to the param.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't pass a parameter, it would be `undefined`, not `null`.

If you want to skip the first parameter, you still have to pass it in, just pass it in as something falsy (assuming your `doSomething` function handles that case).

```js
const data = 'foo';

function doSomething(param1, param2) {
    if (param1) console.log(param1);
    if (param2) console.log(param2);
}

doSomething(null, data);
```

If you a similar functionality to Python, you can take in a single parameter, which is an object.

```js
const data = 'foo';

function doSomething({ param1, param2 }) {
    if (param1) console.log(param1);
    if (param2) console.log(param2);
}

doSomething({ param2: data });
```